# AngularJS ui-router abstract state with second child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, abstract

I have a problem to load second child of state. Url is changed, but page not loading.

```
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        controller: 'myControl',
        data: {
            requireLogin: true
        }
    })
    .state('app.CarsList', {
        params: { id: ':id' },
        url: '/Companies/:name',
        templateUrl: 'CarsList.html',
    })

    .state('app.CarsList.CarInfo', {// second child
        url: '/Info',
        templateUrl: "CarInfo.html"
    })
```

Comment: There's an unnecessary `,` in the first child; Also, does the state changes and you don't see anything or the state doesn't change at all?

Comment: Thanks Tom Arad. All pages is loading, but templateUrl' s  second state not Loaded.

Comment: How does CarsList.html look like? Is it possible that you forgot a `ui-view` in there?

Comment: Say YOU that I Remove ui-view in app state?!

Comment: No, because `app.CarsList.CarInfo` is a child of `app.CarsList` there needs to be a `ui-view` in the HTML of `app.CarsList`.

Comment: ok, insert <div ui-view></div> into HTML of app.CarsList. Now new problem. new page load, but last page (CarsList) is open

Comment: It seems like  a logical error, looks like you want `CarInfo` to be a child of `app` and not `app.CarsList`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cx1v67ut/ Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a ui-view in the CarsList.html, child states will load their templates into their parent's ui-view.

Check the [Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

Comment: ok, insert <div ui-view></div> into HTML of app.CarsList. Now new problem. new page load, but last page (CarsList) is open yet!

Comment: if you don't want to load CarsList then change the third state from 'app.CarsList.CarInfo' to 'app.CarInfo'.

Comment: no, I load **app.CarsList.CarInfo**  form **app.CarsList** , but don't want to load CarsList in CarInfo

Comment: can you share the html files, its simpler to understand the problem. you can use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and put the link here.

Comment: you don't want the html code above the <div ui-view></div> to load right?

Comment: 'help me' for this problem

Comment: then you don't need the nested state. just change the state from `'app.CarsList.CarInfo'` to only `'app.CarInfo'` and then change the link your html `ui-sref="app.CarsList.CarInfo"` to `ui-sref="app.CarInfo"`. if you make the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cx1v67ut/) complete and working, i will help you there.

Comment: thanks @mike, I already use this case But Url parameters is removed.

              http://localhost:40234/Root/Home.html#/Companies/Ford/Info >

              http://localhost:40234/Root/Home.html#/Companies//Info

Comment: if you want to you could use localhost:40234/Root/Home.html#/Companies/Info/ford and add the url parameter on `'app.CarsList.CarInfo'` state

Comment: if all this info helps you may mark this answer as answer